# Creating a pattern in an array

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have an array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.zeros(15)
```

And a pattern `[1,2,3]` that needs to be learned.
Meaning, I'd like the array to have this pattern.
The difficulty is learning a function that outputs this pattern, or as close as possible, given any pattern or array.
Currently I have the function hard coded:

```
def rule(array, item_idx):
    try:
        left_nbr = array[item_idx-1]
        right_nbr = array[item_idx+1]
        
        if left_nbr == 0 and right_nbr == 0:
            array[item_idx] = 1
            
        if arr[item_idx] == 0 and left_nbr == 1:
                    array[item_idx] = 2
                
        if arr[item_idx] == 0 and left_nbr == 2:
                    array[item_idx] = 3
                
        if arr[item_idx] == 0 and left_nbr == 3:
                    array[item_idx] = 1
    except IndexError:
        pass

    return array


for i in range (0,len(arr)):
    arr = rule(arr, i)
    print(arr)

>>>
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 2. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 2. 3. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 0. 0.]
[1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 0.]
[1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 0.]
```

Is there a way to have a machine learning model that learns the rules (i.e. replace the function `rule`) to output the pattern? That is, instead of me hard coding the rules.

**Update 1:**
I tried creating a model using PyTorch but it doesn't seem to be able to learn the pattern (the loss doesn't decrease at all):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

pattern = torch.tensor([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1])

def custom_loss(output, target):
    loss = torch.tensor(target - output).sum()
    loss.requires_grad = True
    return loss

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Linear(3,1)
        )

learning_rate = 1e-3
optimizer = torch.optim.RMSprop(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

for t in range(2000):
    x = torch.zeros(10)

    for i in range (0,len(pattern)):
        try:
            left_nbr = x[i-1]
            center = x[i]
            right_nbr = x[i+1]
            
            output = model(torch.tensor([left_nbr, center, right_nbr]))
            x[i] = int(output)
        except IndexError:
            pass
            
    loss = custom_loss(x, pattern)
    if t % 100 == 0:
        print(t, loss.item())

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Comment: You said your model needs to learn the pattern `[1, 2, 3]` and make it look like your input vector space is the length of `15` by the `rule`. You would better be clear how long input your model can take and which kind of prediction you really want to make.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

I observed that the prediction has never changed.

```
    output = model(torch.tensor([left_nbr, center, right_nbr]))
    x[i] = int(output)

    ...

loss = custom_loss(x, pattern)
```

I observed that `output < 1`, and thus, `int(output) == 0`.
So, it seems like that your target to compute loss against is always `[0, ..., 0].`

`loss` will never change because predictions are always the same.

Additionally, I am not sure what you want to do, however, it would be better to use your model's output as input for a loss function.

#### Quick Fix

Deep learning is good for classification, rather than regression, based on its ability to deeply extract features.
Check [this](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/faq.html) how model predicts numbers written in images. It does not predict a real number of the range `[0, 9]`, instead, it predicts fixed number of real numbers of the range `[0, 1]`, thus, something like `[0.1, ..., 0.9]`. The position itself of the highest number is the number, thus class.

So, try the following code. This is how we usually use PyTorch.

```
data = [
    ([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0.]),
    ([1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]),
    ([1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [1., 0., 0.]),
    ([1., 2., 3., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0.]),
    ([1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]),
    ([1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [1., 0., 0.]),
    ([1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0.]),
    ([1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]),
    ([1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [1., 0., 0.]),
    ([1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0.]),
    ([1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]),
    ([1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0.], [1., 0., 0.]),
    ([1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0.]),
    ([1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]),
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Linear(15, 30),
        nn.Sigmoid(),
        torch.nn.Linear(30, 10),
        nn.Sigmoid(),
        torch.nn.Linear(10, 3),
        nn.Sigmoid()
    )

    learning_rate = 1e-3
    optimizer = torch.optim.RMSprop(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
    mse = nn.MSELoss()

    for t in range(10000):
        X, y = random.choice(data)
        output = model(torch.tensor(X, requires_grad=False))

        loss = mse(output, torch.tensor(y, requires_grad=False))
        if t % 100 == 0:
            print(t, loss.item())

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

#### Better Fix

Since your input is a sequence, you would better use [Recurrent Neural Network (RNN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network).

Comment: Not entirely sure I follow. `x` is changing in `x[i] = int(output)`, and hence I am using the `model's` output

Comment: @Penguin Ah, okay I made a wrong assumption based on my observation. I will edit.

Comment: @Penguin Edited. Please check it.

Comment: It makes sense now why the loss doesn't decrease. Though, I'm not sure why `output` is always `< 1`. I'm trying to create a model that can learn the rules to get the pattern. If you look at my original question, I created a function called `rule` that has hard coded rules to get the pattern. I'm trying to replace it with a trainable model. Hence I wasn't sure how to use the model's output as inputs for the loss function

Comment: So you want to predict `2` for `[1, 0, ..., 0]` and `3` for `[1, 2, 0, ..., 0]`?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. For that particular pattern

Comment: @Penguin Please check and accept it if you like it.

Comment: I appreciate all the help! And you're right, I was going for regression, hence the `torch.nn.Linear(3,1)`. Are you saying this will always produce a value between `[0,1]`? A problem with your approach is that I don't have `data`. The problem above is just a toy example, and in real life I have to solve something much more complex. Hence, producing `data` beforehand is unrealistic. Though, I do see how much easier it is to use it. I was hoping that there is a way to use the model several times as I tried (`for i in range (0,len(pattern)):`) before calculating the loss

Comment: Also, RNNs would be great, but as I mentioned above the problem in real life that I'm trying to solve is much more complex (2D or 3D patterns). Similar idea though. Based on the neighbors of each `center_value` I need to learn a function that will modify it to reach a pattern

Comment: @Penguin `torch.nn.Linear` is just a matrix multiplication. Its elements are usually set small, however, it can produce any real numbers. If you suffer from data insufficiency which is common in real world, you can artificially generate data to feed your model. So, producing `data` beforehand is very **realistic** approach. You can modify the method `rule` to produce data.

Comment: @Penguin If you want to consider neighbors, you can try CNN. And please accept the answer (solved your loss problem) if helpful. :)

Comment: Again, I really appreciate the help! You helped me understand quite a few things, but as I mentioned, producing `data` is not possible for this problem. 1 reason for that is that the number of possible permutations is just too large. For example, the array can be `[0,0,...0]`, or `[1,1,...0]`, or `[1,0,1,...0]` or `[1,2,1,...0]`,etc. Producing a `y` for each one is not realistic. I'm looking for a function that can take any array and a pattern, and produce the rules to get there (or as close as possible). Please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: @Penguin **It is indeed possible**. For example, predicting next word in machine translation is to pick a word from all possible words which is tens of thousands. 1M of 4-byte float numbers is just 4 MB. And, your question is about why your loss does not decrease.

Comment: @Penguin I spent my time to help you and solved your problem about the loss. Please do not make it I wasted my time...

Comment: My question was about finding the function that will produce the rules given any initial array and a pattern. My update was an attempt in doing so. A problem I found in my update was that the loss was not decreasing. The fact that the loss was not decreasing doesn't change the original question. Again, I appreciate your help

Comment: @Penguin My answer satisfyies all your need. 1. You have to modify your `rule` to artificially generate data. 2. **You think it is not possible, however, it is possible**. 3. It fixed your loss problem and It works.